# Образование женского рода

Tags: словообразование

Отчего зависит, какое будет окончание, когда от мужского рода образуется женский? То есть, почему, например, "танцовщик - танцовщица", то "пловец - пловчиха"? Более того, мы привыкли говорить "волчица", а у Чехова в рассказе "Белолобый" - "волчиха".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правил однозначных нет, есть закономерности.
Более древние образования тяготеют к -иха, современные - к -ица.
А вообще вопрос необъятный, я, если найду, подкину ссылочку, попадалось где-то совсем недавно, но не сохранил.

Comment: А почему аналогичным соотношением связаны стол - столица? Случайно ли это совпадение?

Comment: Не совсем аналогичным.   
-иц 0 суффикс многозначный, он обозначает тне только жкеский род от соответвующего мужского. В данном случае он образует существительное не напрямую от "стол", а от "стольный". Аналогично в "поленица", "ключица" и т.д. И бюизкое горчица - не от горечь, а от "горчить".

Comment: Со столицей и горчицей понятно. Вы имели в виду "поленица" или "поленница"? Поленница - от "полено", но в каком смысле использован суффикс? А уж "поленица" - "богатырь" - вообще не понятно от чего. 

С ключицей тоже не очень понятно. Какой же смысл имеет суффикс в четырех приведенных Вами словах?

Comment: >>>Вы имели в виду "поленица" или "поленница"? 
Снимаю поленицу. Тут дейстуительно разбираться надо. 
А вот поленница - пойдёт, пожалуй, но там второе Н от суффиуса, так что неинтересно.

Какой же смысл имеет суффикс в четырех приведенных Вами словах?
Суффикс "-иц", как и сказал, он может возникать в тех случаях, когда образование идёт не напрямую от слова, а опосредовано через производное и/или менять значение.